# Dúvida ao montar um where em uma Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

No site, tenho um filtro que já funciona. Esse filtro será mantido, mas a tabela será outra, de outro banco inclusive.
A regra para o filtro é, se o parâmetro passado for:

- Igual a `1`, traz somente os abertos.
- Igual a `2`, traz os pagos.
- Igual a `3`, traz tudo.

Então as regras de `aberto` e `pago` são:

```
E2_VALOR > 0  # (ABERTO)
E2_VALOR = 0  # (PAGO)
```

A questão é que o como eu passo isso no where do select da PROC. Abaixo a **PROC**

```
DECLARE
@CodTerceiro int = 243664,  
@DataVencimentoIni datetime = null,   
@DataVencimentoFim datetime = null,   
@Pago  tinyint = 3 

SELECT pw.IdPedidoWeb,  
    pw.IdPedido, 
    Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_EMISSAO,103) as 'DataEmissao' ,  
    Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103) as 'DataVencimento',     
    pedido.C5_XIDNF AS 'IdNotaFiscal',    
    notafiscal.F2_DOC AS NroNotaFiscal, 
    receber.E1_VALOR AS VlrTotalNotaFiscal,
         
    CASE WHEN receber.E1_SALDO > 0
    THEN 'Em Aberto'
    ELSE 'Pago'
    END 'Status',
            
    pw.CodProduto,    
    pw.QtdItem,    
    pw.QtdItem * pw.VlrVenda 'VlrProduto'    
FROM [dbo].[PedidoWeb] pw    
    WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX (Ind_PedidoWeb_2)) 
    INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SC5010 pedido
    WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON pedido.C5_XPEDSND = pw.IdPedido

    INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SE1010 receber 
    WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON receber.E1_FILIAL = pedido.C5_FILIAL
    and receber.E1_NUM = pedido.C5_NOTA
           
    INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SF2010 notafiscal
    ON notafiscal.F2_DOC = pedido.C5_NOTA
    AND notafiscal.F2_FILIAL = pedido.C5_FILIAL
    AND notafiscal.F2_FILIAL = receber.E1_FILIAL

    WHERE pw.CodTerceiro = 243664    
    AND Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103) >= coalesce (@DataVencimentoIni, Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103))    
    AND Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103) <= coalesce (@DataVencimentoFim, Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103))    
    --AND (   @Pago = 3    
    --    OR @Pago = CASE WHEN receber.E1_SALDO > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
     
    --AND ( ( @pago = 1 and receber.E1_SALDO > 0)
    --        Or
    --        ( @pago = 2 and receber.E1_SALDO = 0)
    --        Or
    --        ( @pago = 3) )

                
                
    AND pw.IdPedidoWEb between '9000000' and '20000000' 
    --222794
    --SELECT CASE WHEN receber.E1_SALDO > 0
    --THEN 'Em Aberto'
    --ELSE 'Pago'
    --END 'Status' FROM TOTVS12.DBO.SE1010 receber WHERE E1_NUM = '2368332'
```

e essa é a query antiga, que estou tendo que substituir, porque a tabela Notafiscal não mais vai ser usada, tudo virá do PROTHEUS

```
DECLARE
@CodTerceiro int = 243664,  
@DataVencimentoIni datetime = null,   
@DataVencimentoFim datetime = null,   
@Pago  tinyint = 3


SELECT pw.IdPedidoWeb,  
             pw.IdPedido,  
             cr.DataEmissao,   
             pc.DataVencimento,   
             nf.IdNotaFiscal,  
             cr.NroNotaFiscal,   
             cr.VlrTotalNotaFiscal,  
             CASE WHEN cr.SaldoAbertoNF > 0   
                  THEN 'Em Aberto'  
                  ELSE 'Pago'  
             END 'Status',  
             pw.CodProduto,  
             pw.QtdItem,  
             pw.QtdItem * pw.VlrVenda 'VlrProduto'  
         FROM [dbo].[PedidoWeb] pw  
            WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX (Ind_PedidoWeb_2))  
            
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[NotaFiscal] nf  
            WITH (NOLOCK)  
            ON nf.IdPedido = pw.IdPedido  
            
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[ContasReceber] cr  
            ON cr.idContasReceber = nf.IdContasReceber  
            
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[ParcelaContasReceber] pc  
            ON pc.idContasReceber = nf.IdContasReceber  
           AND pc.IdParcelaContasReceber = (SELECT min (p1.IdParcelaContasReceber)  
                                            FROM [dbo].[ParcelaContasReceber] p1  
                                            WHERE p1.idContasReceber = nf.IdContasReceber)  
         WHERE pw.CodTerceiro = 243664  
           AND pc.DataVencimento >= coalesce (@DataVencimentoIni, pc.DataVencimento)  
           AND pc.DataVencimento <= coalesce (@DataVencimentoFim, pc.DataVencimento)  
           AND (   @Pago = 3  
                OR @Pago = CASE WHEN cr.SaldoAbertoNF > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)  
           
           AND pw.IdPedidoWEb between '9000000' and '20000000'
```

A **query** antiga traz 104 registros entre **Pagos** e **Em Aberto** e a nova **query** traz apenas 60 registros e somente **Pagos**, mesmo eu trocando o filtro **@Pago** para 1. Percebi que registros na **query** nova que estão como pagos, na **query** antiga estão como **Em Aberto**

Comment: O que faz este trecho?   `AND pc.DataVencimento >= coalesce (null, pc.DataVencimento)    
           AND pc.DataVencimento <= coalesce (null, pc.DataVencimento)`    !!!

Comment: Está errado o texto, copiei errado. `AND pc.DataVencimento >= coalesce (@DataVencimentoIni, pc.DataVencimento) AND pc.DataVencimento <= coalesce (@DataVencimentoFim, pc.DataVencimento)`

Comment: Ao perguntar sobre um problema no seu código, você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Veja como criar um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) para utilizar na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Apenas o filtro, uma solução

```
( ( @pago = 1 and SaldoAbertoNF > 0)
  Or
  ( @pago = 2 and SaldoAbertoNF = 0)
  Or
  ( @pago = 3) )
```

Comment: Motta, vou testar.